Annullment of Marriage or Emancipation of Married Slave Girl After Husband Bought Her?
If a free man who married a slave girl (someone else's] buys her will she is becomes automatically free or is it the choice of her husband to annul the marriage and keep her as concubine?
Confused while reading a section related to chapter on tricks to evade Istibara "إعلام الموقعين عن رب العالمين" because Imam didn't mention whether she is free after husband buy her
Here is the text

"[فَصْلٌ إبْطَالُ حِيلَةٍ لِإِسْقَاطِ الِاسْتِبْرَاءِ] فَصْلٌ
[إبْطَالُ حِيلَةٍ لِإِسْقَاطِ الِاسْتِبْرَاءِ] وَمِنْ الْحِيَلِ
الْمُحَرَّمَةِ الْبَاطِلَةِ أَنْ يَشْتَرِيَ جَارِيَةً وَيُرِيدَ
وَطْأَهَا بِمِلْكِ الْيَمِينِ فِي الْحَالِ مِنْ غَيْرِ اسْتِبْرَاءٍ
فَلَهُ عِدَّةُ حِيَلٍ، مِنْهَا: أَنْ يُزَوِّجَهُ إيَّاهَا الْبَائِعُ
قَبْلَ أَنْ يَبِيعَهَا مِنْهُ، فَتَصِيرُ زَوْجَتَهُ، ثُمَّ يَبِيعُهُ
إيَّاهَا فَيَنْفَسِخُ النِّكَاحُ، وَلَا يَجِبُ عَلَيْهِ اسْتِبْرَاءٌ؛
لِأَنَّهُ مِلْكُ زَوْجَتِهِ، وَقَدْ كَانَ وَطْؤُهَا حَلَالًا لَهُ
بِعَقْدِ النِّكَاحِ؛ فَصَارَ حَلَالًا بِمِلْكِ الْيَمِينِ."

Source:
https://app.turath.io/book/11496?page=847

If a man marries a slave girl (belonging to some else) and then purchases her then his marriage to that slave will be nullified and she will remain his slave.
Ref:

ولو ملك زوجته، وهي أمة، انفسخ نكاحها، وكذلك لو ملكت المرأة زوجها، انفسخ نكاحها، ولا نعلم في هذا خلافا
If he is married to a slave woman and then becomes her owner then the marriage contract is annulled (on gaining ownership); the same applies if a woman becomes the owner of her husband, her marriage contract is annulled. We do not know of any difference of opinion concerning this.
— al-Mughni

